# Show that $\pi_1(D^2)$ is the trivial set, by showing that $D^2$ is a contractible space.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I have to show that $\pi_1(D^2) = 0$. I can't use the fact that $D^2$ is convex, instead I have to show that $D^2$ is contractible and thus simply connected.

I know that:

**Def:** A space X is called contractible if X is homotopy equivalent with a point.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to work with this!

**Q:** How do I show that $D^2$ is contractible, by using the definition given above?

Comment: Can you show that $[0,1]$ is contractible ?

Comment: $D^2$ is the disk in plane? Why can't you use that $D^2$ is convex? Convex sets and star-convex sets are contractible.

Comment: Yes I know but this is an exercise to practise with contractibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in D^2$, so is $tx$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. ($||x|| \le 1$ implies $||tx|| = |t|\cdot||x||\le |t| \le 1$). So $H(x,t) = (1-t)(x)$ from $D^2 \times [0,1]$ to $D^2$ is an homotopy between $1_{D^2}$ and the constant map with value $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What does $1_{D^2}$ mean though? :)

Comment: @titusAdam the identity function on $D^2$.